# Prevent json_encode from escaping with double dashes

Tags: php, arrays, json

Is there a way to **prevent** php `json_encode` to escape `\n\r...` characters?

I've tried with the flags `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, but it doesn't seems to work.

My string is something similar to `"<p>Test string...</p>\n\r<p>Another text...</p>"`

The result after `json_encode` and `decode` is:

```
"<p>Test string...</p>\\n\\r<p>Another text...</p>"
```

I want to get the same string as the initial one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Literal backslashes always have to be escaped in JSON strings.

Comment: except str_replace, is there another solution?

Comment: To what purpose? Does something depend on invalid JSON? Your actual issue are unprocessed C escape sequences from somewhere earlier. Figure out how that happened, and fix it there.

Comment: I'm experimenting with storing sql select statements as part of encoded array. I'm sure that the sql string is properly escaped. Using simple text file and serialize|unserialize works fine but it is very "ugly" and not cross platform.

Comment: So your real question is how to *undo* proper SQL escaping partially.

Comment: Thanks @mario, maybe you are right, but unfortunately the sql strings comes from a sql file...nevermind I will stuck with the serialize|unserialize method. If no one has other ideas, I will delete the question. .